# adding source(src) of image to formData and posting it to backend via http post call

Tags: javascript, jquery, form-data

I have an img tag with src="fast.jpg". I want to get the image picked from my source folder add it to form data and send it via http post call

html:

```
<img src="fast.jpg" data-highres="fast.jpg"  
style="width:150px;height:150px;"id="img1"  onclick="myFunction(this);" >
```

javascript:

```
var img = document.getElementById($(target).attr("id")).src

console.log("img>>>>",img)

var files = img.files
console.log("files", files)
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('pic[]', img.name);

console.log("formdata>>", formData)
```

post call:

```
    xhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:5001/testpost", true);
    xhttp.withCredentials = false;
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache", "no-cors");
    xhttp.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need add Content-type for `XMLHttpRequest`
//Set header information along with the request

```
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

And your file content is not correct, you need use input `type="file"` to select image, img tag only for preview upload image.

Comment: I have few image thumnails and onclick of those images i need post call to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Make the image input inside a form with an id, and use:

```
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="file" name="myPicture">
</form>
```

In your js code, send the form, like so:

```
var formData = new FormData( $('form#myForm')[0] );
```

Comment: I cannot use form tag since i have an image gallery in the UI and onclick of any images i want the image picked from src and make a post call

Comment: Images in gallery couldn't be loaded from local file system but from a server, and you need to post the image. I couldn't understand. if you could explain more so I can help